# Add a column to a dataframe based on a probability distribution

Tags: r, data-imputation

Suppose I have two dependent categorical attributes A, B. I have a dataframe X that lists probabilities (or expected counts) for all combinations of all categories of A and B. Let's assume two categories in each attribute, the dataframe could then look like this:

```
X <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,2,2), B = 1:2, PROB = c(0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4))
X
```

Output:

```
  A B PROB
1 1 1   .1
2 1 2   .3
3 2 1   .2
4 2 2   .4
```

Now I would like to add a B column to another dataframe Y that has only an A column. Y exists and has many more rows than X, and also additional columns. A synthetic Y could look like this:

```
Y <- data.frame(A=sample(2, size=10000, replace=TRUE),
                B=NA,
                C=sample(5, size=10000, replace=TRUE),
                D=sample(3, size=10000, replace=TRUE))
```

The contents of the new B column should be sampled at random using the conditional probabilities for B given the value of the A column.

I am new to R, and I was wondering whether this operation can be handled more elegantly than writing a loop that iterates over all A categories. Perhaps a dedicated model class for which `predict` could be applied? Also, I lack the knowledge of statistical terminology -- I would appreciate any hint on how this kind of imputation (?) is referred to in the literature.

Comment: `PROB` is the overall probability, it sums up to 1 in my toy dataframe. In `Y$B`, I want the value 2 to appear about three times as often as the value 1 in those rows that have `A=1`. For the rows with `A=2`, this ratio should be 2:1 (=0.4/0.2).

Comment: OK, so in the final dataframe only these conditional amounts should count and PROB won't come out the same as here. That had me stumped for a bit because your toy Y has equal probability 1 and 2 for A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that if Y doesn't actually already exist you probably want to just make it from scratch like this.

```
Y <- X[sample(1:nrow(X), size = 10000, replace = TRUE, prob = X$PROB),]
Y <- Y[,-3]
```

BTW, you can test to see that you got what you want with...

```
table(factor(Y$A):factor(Y$B))/nrow(Y)
```

If Y really does already exist then yes, you have to go through the unique values of A, but not all values of A.

```
b <- lapply(unique(X$A), function(x){
    n <- nrow(Y[Y$A==x,])
    df <- X[X$A == x,]
    Y$B[Y$A==x] <<- with( df, sample(B, n, replace = TRUE, prob = PROB) )
    })
```

In that case `b` is garbage.  A `for` loop version of this wouldn't even make the garbage `b`

```
for(x in unique(X$A)){
    n <- nrow(Y[Y$A == x,])
    df <- X[X$A == x,]
    Y$B[Y$A == x] <- with( df, sample(B, n, replace = TRUE, prob = PROB) )
    }
```

And thus... this might be a case where using a `loop` is the cleanest way to go.  :)

I did some quick time testing of these two methods and the plyr version.  The fastest is the `for` loop, followed by `lapply`, followed by (far in the back), `ddply` (50% with given dataset).  The cost gets bigger as Y grows in either size or complexity such that the `for` loop can get 2 to 5x the performance of `ddply` and it uses much less memory.

Comment: +1 for the `table` test. Is there really no shortcut for this assignment in R? I was thinking about a dedicated model class for which `predict` could be applied.

Comment: `predict` couldn't work since it doesn't give random outcomes but fixed ones.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ddply` (from `plyr` package) first to create the conditional probabilities:

```
Xcond<-ddply(X, .(A),
             .fun=function(curdfr){
                 curdfr$CPROB<-curdfr$PROB/sum(curdfr$PROB);curdfr})
```

Now, given Y with column A, you can get the result you want e.g. by (if the order is not of importance to you):

```
ddply(Y, .(A), .fun=function(curdfr){
  curA<-curdfr[1,"A"]
  curOrg<-Xcond[Xcond$A==curA,]
  curN<-nrow(curdfr)
  curB<-sample(curOrg$B, size=nrow(curdfr), replace=TRUE, prob=curOrg$CPROB)
  curdfr$B<-curB
  curdfr
})
```

No doubt there are more elegant/efficient solutions. Read its help if you don't understand the `ddply` call - if that fails, get back to us.

**Edit** as per @John's suggestion: X can be used immediately instead of Xcond:

```
ddply(Y, .(A), .fun=function(curdfr){
  curA<-curdfr[1,"A"]
  curOrg<-X[X$A==curA,]
  curN<-nrow(curdfr)
  curB<-sample(curOrg$B, size=nrow(curdfr), replace=TRUE, prob=curOrg$PROB)
  curdfr$B<-curB
  curdfr
})
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, that's definitely more elegant (and should be faster, too!) than looping through categories.

Comment: Actually, that's less efficient than looping through categories.

Comment: The first run to modify X is unnecessary.  It will work fine with the original X.  The values in prob for sample don't have to add to 1.0.  The relative amounts will work.